# Convert Sql command to Linq or lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have following sql command

```
SELECT e1.name,e1.id,e1.categoryid,e2.name as categoryname
FROM   Category e1 
left join  Category e2 
ON e2.id = e1.CategoryId
```

I want to convert it to linq to sql or lamda but I don't know how do it
I also tried this  code

```
  var query = from q in web.Categorys
                     join q1 in web.Categorys
                         on q.Id equals q1.CategoryId into j
                     select j;
```

but the It's result is different from sql command(it has many null rows!)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
var query = from q in web.Categorys
            from q1 in web.Categorys.Where(x=> x.id == q.CategoryId ).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select q;
```

Comment: although this is not my answer but you gave me a clue to solve it